# How do I compute the point of a triangle-ray intersection?

Tags: collision-detection, mathematics, vector, geometry, intersection

I have a line (the direction vector of the player) and a triangle representing the face of a model (so composed of 3 points).

I can't find the mathematical operation to check if that vector is intersecting with this triangle, and how far from the player...

Comment: Have you Googled "ray triangle intersection"?  Ray will likely get more hits than vector, and there are lots of articles and sample code out there.

Comment: http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html has a bunch of intersection tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, lines are a poor approximation of a user's movement because they don't account for the size of the player.

You want "sweep sphere triangle intersection", also called "capsule triangle intersection".  http://xania.org/Games has a good overview of this.

Comment: *"lines are a poor approximation of a user's movement"* -- unless the player is well-approximated by a point. (While this is helpful, it doesn't answer the question.)

Comment: @Anko kind of true, but on the other hand, cameras are not well approximated by a point if you want to avoid front plane clipping glitches; if you're doing true 3D movement in a 3D world, you end up having to do approximate something bigger than a point eventually.

Comment: Good point -- I was neglecting the third dimension.